# Disable caching for IE 8

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to disable caching for IE8. Is the code snippet below wrong ?

```
<IfModule %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != "MSIE [6-8]">
       Some caching code
</IfModule>
```